# need help, 2 submit forms in 1 ajax send post to 1 file.php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

hello i need to post 2 forms using single ajax or jquery to 1 commun file, the code i have is this

```
<form id="filter-group1" class="form" target="remember" autocomplete="on" method="post">
    <input pattern="[0-9]*" value="" name="ch1" maxlength="10" size="10" autofocus="" autocorrect="off" id="client-nbr" class="form-control numeric" rv-value-reactive="form.idTelematique" type="tel">
    <a class="reset-input" href="#" id="initClient" onclick="change()"></a>
    <input value="" id="memoriser" name="memoriser" type="checkbox">
    <button type="submit" id="remember_button" class="hidden"></button>
</form>

<form id="filter-group2" method="post" class="form">
    <div class="field-password">
        <input  rv-value="form.password | starPassword" readonly="" maxlength="6" name="staredPassword" id="secret-nbr" class="form-control" type="password">
        <a class="reset-input" href="#" id="initPass" onclick="change1()"></a>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="cell-password">
    <div class="field-valid">
        <button type="button" href="#" class="btn-primary btn-block" onclick="filterBy()" id="submitIdent" rv-text="config.app.identification.boutonTitle" >submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function filterBy() { 
    // Construct data string 
    var dataString = $("#filter-group1, #filter-group2").serialize(); 
    // Log in console so you can see the final serialized data sent to AJAX 
    console.log(dataString); 
    // Do AJAX 
    $.ajax( { 
        type: 'POST', 
        url: 'filter.php', 
        data: dataString, 
        success: function(data) { 
            console.log(data);
            $('#message').html(data);
        } 
    }); 
}
```

`<button type="button"` need to submit 2 the forms using ajax to post in single file php

---

problem not solve make me a full script if you can't, when i try to clik on `<button type="button" href="#" class="btn-primary btn-block" onclick="filterBy()"`  function not execute

Comment: function filterBy() { 
    // Construct data string
    var dataString = $("#filter-group1, #filter-group2").serialize();

    // Log in console so you can see the final serialized data sent to AJAX
    console.log(dataString);

    // Do AJAX
    $.ajax( {
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'filter.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $('#message').html(data);
        }
    });
}

Comment: You mean you want one click to submit both forms, one after the other, to a single web service?

Answer (score 0):

change to create your datastring:

```
var dataString = {
                   frm1 : $("#filter-group1").serialize(),
                   frm2 : $("#filter-group2").serialize()
                 };
```

and at the php end you can get the values with keys `frm1, frm2`.

Comment: i just try this but onclick="filterBy()" function not execute ?

Comment: open console and check for error messages on click.